# jdb maven: InstallMojo source

Tags: debugging, maven-plugin, jdb

I try to debug `install::install` using `mvnDebug`/`jdb -attach 8000`
I get easily to `org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager:101`
and then step on `mojo.execute()` which leads me to:

```
main[1] where
  [1] org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo.execute (InstallMojo.java:76)
  [2] org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
...
```

I find the sources for InstallMojo.java from svn, but how should I know what tag to checkout?
Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Do you know the version of the install plugin you want to analyze ?

Comment: Sorry... I didn't notice your question: 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the given information you are using the 2.3.1 version of the maven-install-plugin you can simply read the pom file of that particular version which means search for that version in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmaven-install-plugin). And the [pom file](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom) will give you the information you need:

Excerpt:

```
<scm><connection>scm:svn:http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1</developerConnection>
```

This gives you the exact location of the SVN Tag in the apache SVN repository and of course the correct location which you can checkout.